# ie9 dropdown not set to the first value

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

###########Update

Here is the original code that worked in ie7 but not in 9. I updated and thought both were ok.

```
if(max_ch>0){
var newDiv = $('<div>Room '+(i+1)+
    ' <select class="adu" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+
    '][adults][]"></select> adults. <select class="chi" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+
    ']['+ro_id+'][children][]"></select> children.</div>'
);
newDiv.attr("id","occupants"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

var roomPrice = $('<input type="hidden" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][prices][]" value="'+room_bo+'" />');
roomPrice.attr("id","roomprice"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

var num_opts = Number(max_ad) + 1,
    slc_adu = $(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.adu');
for( ad=0; ad < num_opts; ad++){
    slc_adu.append("<option value=\"" + ad + "\">" + ad + "</option>");
}

var num_opts = Number(max_ch) + 1,
    slc_ch = $(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.chi');
for( ch=0; ch < num_opts; ch++){
    slc_ch.append("<option value=\"" + ch + "\">" + ch + "</option>");
}

$(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.adu').val('1');
```

}

I have some jquery to build drop-down boxes. I want the drop-downs to have the first value already selected in them. This happens on all browser except ie9.

It has a blank record as the first value.

```
            $('.rooms_select select' ).change(function(){

                var showdiv = '#div_'+$(this).attr('id');
                var r_id    = $(showdiv+' .rate_data').val();
                var ro_id   = $(showdiv+' .room_data').val();
                var min_ad  = $(showdiv+' .room_data').attr('minadults');                   
                var max_ad  = $(showdiv+' .room_data').attr('maxadults');
                var max_ch  = $(showdiv+' .room_data').attr('maxchildren');
                var total_price = $(showdiv+' .rate_data').attr('total_price');
                var price_quote = $(showdiv+' .rate_data').attr('rel');
                var rooms = $(this).val();
                var room_bo = 0;

                //$(showdiv+' .room_data').attr('numrooms', rooms);

                room_price = calc_rprice(showdiv,total_price,price_quote,rooms);
                // NEW THING
                room_bo = Number(room_price/rooms);

                $(showdiv).slideDown("slow");
                $(showdiv+' .rooms_adults').html('<span>Please select number of occupants.</span>');
                for( i=0; i < rooms; i++){

                    if(max_ch>0){
                        var newDiv = $('<div>Room '+(i+1)+' <select class="adu" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][adults][]"></select> adults. <select class="chi" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][children][]"></select> children.</div>');
                        newDiv.attr("id","occupants"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

                        var roomPrice = $('<input type="hidden" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][prices][]" value="'+room_bo+'" />');
                        roomPrice.attr("id","roomprice"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

                        var roomTotalPrice = $('<input type="hidden" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][roomTotalPrice][]" value="'+room_price+'" />');
                        roomTotalPrice.attr("id","roomTotalPrice"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

                        var num_opts = Number(max_ad) + 1,
                            slc_adu = $(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.adu');
                        for( ad=min_ad; ad < num_opts; ad++){
                            slc_adu.append("<option value=\"" + ad + "\">" + ad + "</option>");
                        }

                        var num_opts = Number(max_ch) + 1,
                            slc_ch = $(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.chi');
                        for( ch=0; ch < num_opts; ch++){
                            slc_ch.append("<option value=\"" + ch + "\">" + ch + "</option>");
                        }

                        $(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.adu').val('1');
                        $("select :first-child").each(function () {
                            $(this).attr("selected", true);
                        });

                    } else {
                        var newDiv = $('<div>Room '+(i+1)+' <select class="adu" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][adults][]"></select> adults.</div>');         
                        newDiv.attr("id","occupants"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

                        var roomPrice = $('<input type="hidden" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][prices][]" value="'+room_bo+'" />');
                        roomPrice.attr("id","roomprice"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

                        var roomTotalPrice = $('<input type="hidden" name="data[Rate]['+r_id+']['+ro_id+'][roomTotalPrice][]" value="'+room_price+'" />');
                        roomTotalPrice.attr("id","roomTotalPrice"+i).appendTo(showdiv+' .rooms_adults');

                        var num_opts = Number(max_ad) + 1,
                            slc_adu = $(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.adu');
                        for( ad=min_ad; ad < num_opts; ad++){
                            slc_adu.append("<option value=\"" + ad + "\">" + ad + "</option>");
                        }
                        $(showdiv+' #occupants'+i+' select.adu').val('1');
                        $("select :first-child").each(function () {
                            $(this).attr("selected", true);
                        });


                    }

                calc_rprice(showdiv,total_price,price_quote,rooms);


            });
```

Comment: Why are you building all of this HTML inside a JavaScript function? This is a really bad idea. Do you not have any access to a server-side programming language?

Comment: Yes I do, but it depends on the the user clicks, so it has to be javascript

Comment: Why can't you use AJAX and hide these calculations somewhere where, say, prying eyes can't reverse-engineer your form and you can actually apply some OO principles to web development?

Comment: would that be better option then javascript? I could redevelop latter, but for now I need this fix for ie9, thanks

Comment: Yes. Any user with FireBug, etc. can manipulate your scripts. JavaScript code isn't exactly what we would call **secure**.

Comment: Yeah that is an issue, but there is little they can do as the next page recalculate the form anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm loathe to facilitate the continued use of JS like this, but try something like:

```
$("select :first-child").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("selected", true);
});
```

**Edit:** I want to reinforce that this model is an abuse of JavaScript. You may **think** that you've secured your website effectively, but I promise you that security on the web is an illusion, and using JavaScript like this makes your site an easy target.

You really need to move far, far away from creating your HTML inside of JavaScript. If you absolutely have to have some form of asynchronous page modifications, you should really be using something like AJAX and securing your code elsewhere. You are giving away unneccessary information by exposing this kind of logic to the end-user.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Seriously noted, I think once of I have time I will change to Ajax.

Comment: We've all been there. I'm still maintaining code I wrote that does something very similar to what you've described, so run away while you have the chance! :)

Comment: That worked for ie9 but broken ie7, I have updated the code above to shown where I placed it, no error. But the price does not calculate and when I click anywhere on the screen the form slides up again

Comment: What happens when you change `true` to `selected`? (for clarity's sake: you'll end up with `$(this).attr("selected", "selected");`

Comment: No, the same, actualy there seems to be a problem anyway with the code and ie7. When I click the second onwards dropdown the price does not calculate anymore and when the form slides down from the click event the submit button appears first and then the form slides down with the dropdowns in it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried marking one of your options "selected"?

Here's a good example:
http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/302/jQuery-Change-the-Default-Option-in-a-Select-Listbox

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am not sure how to set the first one as selected as it is a loop